# windows visual studio 2015 C++ でスレッドのスタックサイズを取得する方法

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

表題の通り、windows visual studio 2015 c++ でスレッドのスタックサイズの取得方法を教えていただきたく質問しました。
具体的には_beginthreadex()で生成したスレッドのスタックサイズを取得する方法が知りたいです。マニュアルやＷＥＢを検索してみると、以下のメソッド群を利用することで取得可能なようですが、使い方が分からず困っています。

- GetThreadContext();
- GetThreadSelectorEntry();
- ReadProcessMemory();

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

公式ドキュメントの[Thread Stack Size](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/thread-stack-size)によると、動作中のスレッドのスタックサイズを取得する方法については説明されていません。目的にも依りますが、あまり知るべきではないのかもしれません。もちろんデバッグ情報等を辿れば取得できるとは思います。

なお、スタックサイズはスレッド作成時に指定しますが、未指定時のデフォルト値は.EXEファイル作成時に[LINK.EXEの/STACKオプション](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations)で指定されいます。更に/STACKオプション未指定時のデフォルトは1MBとなっています。.EXEファイルに記録されているデフォルトのスタックサイズは[DUMPBIN.EXEの/HEADERSオプション](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/headers)で確認することができます。

---

> _beginthreadex() に指定したスタックサイズでスレッドが生成されているか確認したかった

質問文に書かれている通りですね。従来CreateToolhelp32Snapshotを含む[Tool Help Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/tool-help-library)ではスタックサイズは取得できませんでした。Windows 8以降には新たに[Process Snapshotting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/proc_snap/process-snapshotting-portal)というライブラリが追加されており、これを使用することで[TEB構造体](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/ns-winternl-_teb)が得られます。TEB構造体がundocumentedながらスタックサイズが含まれていますので、これらを駆使することで得られます。参考までにコードを書いてみました。
このAPIはググっても使用例が出てきませんね。

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <ProcessSnapshot.h>
using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    unsigned tid;
    auto thread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 128 * 1024, [](auto) -> unsigned {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
        return 0;
    }, nullptr, 0, &tid);
    CloseHandle(thread);
    printf("_beginthreadex(): created thread id: %u\n", tid);

    printf("dump all stack sizes.\n");
    HPSS snapshot;
    PssCaptureSnapshot(GetCurrentProcess(), PSS_CAPTURE_THREADS, CONTEXT_ALL, &snapshot);
    HPSSWALK walk;
    PssWalkMarkerCreate(nullptr, &walk);
    for (PSS_THREAD_ENTRY te; PssWalkSnapshot(snapshot, PSS_WALK_THREADS, walk, &te, sizeof te) == ERROR_SUCCESS;) {
        auto teb = reinterpret_cast<const TEB*>(te.TebBaseAddress);
        auto stack_size = static_cast<const char*>(teb->Reserved1[1]) - static_cast<const char*>(teb->Reserved1[2]);
        printf(" tid: % 5u, % 7lldbytes\n", te.ThreadId, stack_size);
    }
    PssFreeSnapshot(GetCurrentProcess(), snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 目的は単純に_beginthreadex() に指定したスタックサイズでスレッドが生成されているか確認したかっただけでした。

Comment: dumpbin の内容も確認したのですが、size of stack reserve の欄は 100000H(1MB)となっており、これはリンカーに指定したデフォルト値？が表示されているだけのようでした。そこで VMMAP を利用してユーザが生成したスレッドのスタックサイズを確認すると、自分が指定したサイズとなっていることは確認できました。（64KBの倍数でない場合は、最寄の64KBの倍数に丸めこまれるようです） 一旦はVMMAPを利用するとこで目的は達成できたので本質問は完了とさせていただきます。

Comment: @oya3  「Windows 8以降」と書いていますが？

Comment: すみませんでした。お手数をお掛けしました。今はwindows7しか環境がなく試せないので自宅にて試してみます。ありがとうございました。（コメントの記載方法が分からず消したりしてしまい申し訳ありません。。。）

Comment: windows10pro 64bit にて上記サンプルコードで確認を行ったところ、VMMAP の”Private WS”の欄が取得できていることがわかりました。